# A load balancer cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same Availability Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

When creating loadbalancer, this error comes.

```
A load balancer cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same Availability Zone (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidConfigurationRequest; Request ID: 9cf9bac5-7725-4ad1-a654-1508c87f4931; Proxy: null
```

I checked the cloud formation file(cdk generated) and found it tries to use plenty of subnets.

```
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
  "Properties": {
    "Subnets": [
      "subnet-00743c1959f30c18d",
      "subnet-0c29ff4d6a38bd7dc",
      "subnet-017c37864a8fa0346",
      "subnet-0c49c99e596f700f8",
      "subnet-035709f658f677d57",
      "subnet-0bd8d61974eb58fe1"
    ],
```

Why does it happens? or how can I avoid this?

My script is here below

```
const lb = new elb.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, "LB", {
  vpc: cluster.vpc,
  loadBalancerName : loadBalancerName,
  internetFacing: false,
  vpcSubnets: {  subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED },
  securityGroup: adminLbSg
});
```

and my subnets are here.

```
{
    "name": "Isolated",
    "type": "Isolated",
    "subnets": [
      {
        "subnetId": "subnet-00743c1959f30c18d",
        "cidr": "10.192.81.0/27",
        "availabilityZone": "ap-northeast-1a",
        "routeTableId": "rtb-0bef9557f97ee4101"
      },
      {
        "subnetId": "subnet-0c29ff4d6a38bd7dc",
        "cidr": "10.192.80.128/27",
        "availabilityZone": "ap-northeast-1a",
        "routeTableId": "rtb-0482688b88c6dc75f"
      },
      {
        "subnetId": "subnet-017c37864a8fa0346",
        "cidr": "10.192.81.32/27",
        "availabilityZone": "ap-northeast-1c",
        "routeTableId": "rtb-09229850ae23576c7"
      },
      {
        "subnetId": "subnet-0c49c99e596f700f8",
        "cidr": "10.192.80.160/27",
        "availabilityZone": "ap-northeast-1c",
        "routeTableId": "rtb-0be8065f125955caa"
      },
      {
        "subnetId": "subnet-035709f658f677d57",
        "cidr": "10.192.81.64/27",
        "availabilityZone": "ap-northeast-1d",
        "routeTableId": "rtb-0b45694166d8258c2"
      },
      {
        "subnetId": "subnet-0bd8d61974eb58fe1",
        "cidr": "10.192.80.192/27",
        "availabilityZone": "ap-northeast-1d",
        "routeTableId": "rtb-0d573c6995fce53b1"
      }
    ]
  },
```

**Solution**

Thank you to @petrch comment.

Basically, the subnets structure is not good.

However, in this case I don't want to change the strucutre of subnets.

So, I quit to use `ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED`

I set pick up each id to set instead.

```
const vpcSubnets = vpc.selectSubnets({
  subnets: [
    ec2.Subnet.fromSubnetAttributes(this, 'subnet-00743c1959f30c18d', {
      subnetId: 'subnet-00743c1959f30c18d', availabilityZone: 'ap-northeast-1a'
    }),
    ec2.Subnet.fromSubnetAttributes(this, 'subnet-017c37864a8fa0346', {
      subnetId: 'subnet-017c37864a8fa0346', availabilityZone: 'ap-northeast-1c'
    }),
  ]
})
```

Comment: sometimes the first good question is why you need the ELB to be in more than one subnets in the same az? if I implemented an ELB functionality with something like ha-proxy, I would probably created ec2 instance in that subnet. I am not sure if you can have an instance in two subnets. If it was just on-prem linux, you need two routing tables based on your configuration, that's possible, but in general, you do not want to do that unless you have to. So again, why you cannot have just one subnet per az? I did not experience any problems with such setup.

Comment: I've got a use-case where I need multiple subnets in the same AZ. Basically my workload is exceeding nat capability so I'd like to split my workload across multiple subnets. (To my knowledge it's not possible to attach two nat gateways to one subnet, or if it is, how would you handle routing?)

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/troubleshooting-configuration.html) a reason and workround

> Instead, consider creating a new environment and perform a CNAME swap.

Comment: I see this downvoted, but I think it is still relevant to the question, because the linked document says: "Changing subnets on the load balancer requires moving it out of the original availability zone(s) and then back into the original with the desired subnets." - so it seems that really the ELB has one internal ENI with an IP from one subnet. It is clearly a design decision which makes implementation much simpler. Also, it is hard to make a strong argument for added value of having the ELB in two subnets in the same AZ.